# Trying to find why my PostAsync(URL,BODY).Results will Time out, but only in .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, docker, httpclient

I'm trying to Create a Docker Container via a POST Request to a REST API.

In .NET Core 2.0 The following Code works

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace DockerDebug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string reply = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient dockerClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("{\"Image\":\"busybox\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    HttpResponseMessage dockerRepsponse = dockerClient .PostAsync("http://localhost:2375/v1.29/containers/create?name=bussybox", httpContent).Result;
                    reply = dockerRepsponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                reply = ex.Message;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

My Docker Environment Does have Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2357 without TLS turned on.

I can run the above command vis a REST Call with Chrome's REST API Plug in, or POSTMAN.

Also the above code works in .NET Core 2.0

but when Building .NET 4.5 & 4.6.1 it times out every time on the PostAsync call.

Comment: How long does it take to timeout on 4.6.1? How long does it take to succeed on .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: 4.6.1 Timeout thrown after 1 min 40 seconds
2.0 Executes in about 1 second

Note: Both Versions actually do make the call to Docker & create the container, just 4.6.1 will not finish so I can get the results.

Comment: What is the value of `reply`?

Comment: Valid = {"Id":"b0336923e3013bffa18661cc2b915479615e33f8ed2576f159f63bb48272b1c2","Warnings":null}
Time out = One or more errors occurred.

With Exception stack trace being
"   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\r\n   at DockerDebug.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\DockerDebug\\DockerDebug\\Program.cs:line 18"

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is to remove the `.Result` you are doing everywhere to forcefully drop async Tasks back to synchronous returns. It is bad and could introduce locks as well as other issues.

Instead a simple fix to convert it to true async and still allow the console to *wait* is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            string reply = string.Empty;

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var httpContent = new StringContent("{\"Image\":\"busybox\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:2375/v1.29/containers/create?name=bussybox", httpContent);
                        reply = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    reply = ex.Message;
                    tcs.TrySetResult(false);
                }
            });

            tcs.Task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically create a `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` and *wait* for that instaed. Then run a new **Task** which will start a background thread and run off the main thread.

Once your task is complete set the **tcs** so that the `Wait()` call continues.

> Here is my video on Threads to help you understand at least Threads, and I will cover Tasks shortly but it should give you some insight into the Task.Run near the very end of the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXg9g56FS0k

See if that fixes your issue. If not it's likely the simple fact the `HttpClient` is implemented differently in .Net Framework than it is in .Net Core. So for that you can change the Timeout to much longer if you like with:

```
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

To set a timeout of 10 minutes.

Between those two things I don't think you should have an issue.

Comment: I've tried the async await both with & without .ConfigureAwait(false)
The Timeout error still occurs, so I never get my valid reply back.
The Function itself is running (Container is created in both version)

Comment: And just ran your code to verify.
Same error "A task was canceled." :(  after 1 min 40 seconds.

Comment: The only 2 things I know of that will trigger a task was canceled are: 1. You canceled it specifically (which your code does not do), or 2. The http call timed out... which suggests the Timeout was not set correct, or in the wrong place, or perhaps .Net Framework is not honouring that. Did you copy my code verbatim?

Comment: You can also check if it was a timeout by doing in the catch statement with: `var wasTimeout = !(ex as TaskCanceledException)?.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`. Note I updated example code how to correctly set timeout

Comment: yes, and just ran with 10 min timeout, took 10 minutes now, but still same time out error.
httpClient.Timeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

Comment: and exception shows IsCancellationRequested = false

Comment: Ok so its likely taking longer than 10 minutes. Can you monitor if your docker is actually created before then?

Comment: Yes, in both the .NET Core 2.0 & .NET 4.6.1 the container itself is created in the first second.
Just that in .NET 4.6.1 it will not return from the call.

Comment: Any reason you are using 4.6.1? I would just use 4.7.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168256/discussion-between-pgp-protector-and-angelsix).